# How to run a specific jquery script after each page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nuxt.js

My client sent me an HTML template that heavily relies on jQuery. The app itself runs on nuxt. I have a js file that contains a whole lot of `$(function(){...})`. Now I don't know how to run this file on each page transition.

So far, I have tried:

1. Creating a `plugin` inside `plugins` dir that looks like:

```
 export default async ({ app }) => {

     app.router.afterEach((to, from) => {
         require('~/static/js/base-init.js');
     })
 }
```

here `base-init.js` has all those jquery code

2. Adding `mounted` (inside `default.vue` layout) but that doesn't work either.

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Could someone please tell me why this question is receiving 'close' votes?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your jquery file on nuxt just do this

Inside your **nuxt.config.js** add

```
npm i jquery

plugins: [
  '~plugins/my-jquery-code.js'
]
```

And inside **plugins/my-jquery-code.js**

```
 if (process.BROWSER_BUILD) {
  const $ = require('jquery')
  $(function() {
  console.log('document ready!');
  // do whatever you want with html and jquery
 })
}
```

I'm refering to this link =>  https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/356

its work for me !
Good Lucks.